# If $D$ be a division ring and $D^*$ be finitely generated group then $D^*$ is abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, division-ring

Wedderburn's little theorem : every finite division ring $D$  is commutative, or $D^*$ is abelian group.

Now  if $D^*$ be a finitely generated group  then  $D^*$ is an abelian group ?

Comment: Just to be sure, when $D$ is a division ring, does $D^*$ infinite and finitely generated ever happen (abelian or not)? Nice question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but it looks as though the question might be hard.

There's a proof for the case where $D$ is finitely generated over its centre in Theorem 1 of

*Akbari, S.; Mahdavi-Hezavehi, M.*, [**Normal subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(D)$ are not finitely generated**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-99-05182-5), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 128, No.6, 1627-1632 (2000). [ZBL0951.20036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0951.20036),

and Conjecture 1 in the same paper is that it's true in general.

Incidentally, it also seems to be an open problem to decide whether an infinite division ring can be finitely generated as a ring (which of course would follow if its group of units were finitely generated as a group). This is referred to as the "Latyshev problem" in [these slides of a 2014 talk by Agata Smoktunovicz](http://www.maths.lth.se/nordic26/media/uploads/smoktunowicz.pdf).